# Firebase User Registration Issue

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hey guys I am setting up user registration for my app, and the registration itself works fine. Like the email and password is saved in my Firebase authentication section, but I am trying to make it so a Username is stored as well. The code I have seems fine to me, but it won't create a Database in my Firebase with any saved user information like the username.

This is the code I am using to register the users.

```
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //start profile activity here

                User user = new User(username, email);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomePage.class ));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Database not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration not successful, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I try to register an account it says "Database not created" so I know that task.isSuccessful() is not true and I am not sure why that is.

Any help?

Comment: [**`task.getException()`**](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L102) will help us both to see what's the actually error.

Comment: I used task.getException() and the exception is "Permission denied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used task.getException() and the exception is "Permission denied"

Which means you are not authenticated to the Firebase. You can make the Firebase rules open to everyone:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

**Which is not a good idea** for security.

> By default, read and write access to your database **is restricted so
>   only authenticated users can read or write data**. To get started
>   without setting up Authentication, you can configure your rules for
>   public access. This does make your database open to anyone, even
>   people not using your app, so be sure to restrict your database again
>   when you set up authentication.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Or, authenticate with the registered user by login the user in then do your `setValue()` or anything on the database.

Use [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Read: [Android Firebase sign in with email and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734226/android-firebase-sign-in-with-email-and-password)

And [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L125).

Comment: So, I have my initial problem solved of the registration failing due to the permission being denied. But now that I have made it public, which hinders the security of the app like you said, it allows the users to register with a username as well as their email. So is there a safer way to let users sign in with a username and have it saved into the Firebase Database?

Comment: Yes. That's why I added the best way actually in the second part of my answer. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477852/4409113). You shouldn't change the rules actually since you're going to release the app too so, you'll need to authenticate the users again and the answer you accepted **is just a workaround**. But, the second part of my answer is your actuall answer to solve all issues. Also, set the rules to when users authenticated like [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477852/4409113) rules.

Answer (score 1):

Change the rules to:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am very new to Firebase so sorry if I am having troubles with simple thing! But I went into my Rules in Firebase and saw this::                                                                                                service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}                                                                                     So is changing the false to a true all I need to do? Or do I need to put the code you showed me somewhere in here?

Comment: It's fine, no need to apologize! Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092843/permission-denied-to-access-firebase-datastore/52092889#52092889 since I think you are using realtime database. The rules that you provided in the comments section are for firestore which is another service.

Comment: This is a **security breach** and it's actually a good idea **for only testing purposes**. But you didn't consider the release build side.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue! I will look into alternative methods in the future so this doesn't hinder the security of my app but for now it's perfect!